# Incomplete for loop with two if-statements

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I've been searching for quite some time on this site now and haven't been able to find the answer to my question.

I'm researching the correlation between several properties of a brook which are all collected in one data frame (PEQTfXS_GrooteMolenbeek). At the moment I'm concentrating at the discharge (PEQTfXS_GrooteMolenbeen$Q) of this brook. What I want to to do is run a for loop through the discharge data and assign the color red if the current value is smaller than the previous value. The color blue will be assigned if the current value is larger than the previous value. In the end, I would like to create a plot of the red and blue data points against the time (PEQTfXS_GrooteMolenbeek$date) if possible.

The loop I have right now is as follows:

```
for (i in 1:length(PEQTfXS_GrooteMolenbeek$Q){
if PEQTfXS_GrooteMolenbeek$Q[i] < PEQTfXS_GrooteMolenbeek$Q[i-1] col = "red"
if PEQTfXS_GrooteMolenbeek$Q[i] > PEQTfXS_GrooteMolenbeek$Q[i-1] col = "blue"
}
```

There seem to be a few things missing from this loop but I don't know what. Besides that, I'm wondering how I can implement the plotting part of my question.

Hopefully this question isn't too stupid. I know there are more easy ways than a for loop but I'm not interested in those ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I like the solution of [Milan Valášek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2062339/milan-val%c3%a1%c5%a1ek) better, since it is more elegant R style, I wanted to provide an answer which covers the part of your question concerning the syntax of the for loop and if statements. I have used some exemplary data, since no reproducible example was available. I hope this helps in terms of syntax.

```
#generate example data
#since your values are integers and your colour codes are characters
#you need separate columns to store them
#character vectors would not be allowed in an integer vector
#(of course you could turn the full vector to character,
#but this would be make the code unnecessarily complex)
values <- rep(c(1,2), 5)
value_color <- rep("", length(values))
df <- data.frame(values = values
                 , value_color = value_color
                 , stringsAsFactors = F)

#since you index i-1, the first entry needs to be decided manually
df[1, "value_color"] <- "red"

#first entry skipped due to manual assignment
#note the brackets around the definition of the loop indices
for (i in 2:length(values) ) {

  #note the brackets around the definition of the expression to
  #be checked via if
  #best practice is to use curly brackets and new line to open if statements
  #for better readability
  #the if statements checks the values in the numeric column called value...
  if (df[i, "values"] < df[i-1, "values"]) {

    #...and assigns the corresponding value in the character column
    df[i, "value_color"]  <- "red"

  } else if (df[i, "values"]  > df[i-1, "values"]) {

    df[i, "value_color"]  <- "blue"

  }
}

df

#      values value_color
# 1       1         red
# 2       2        blue
# 3       1         red
# 4       2        blue
# 5       1         red
# 6       2        blue
# 7       1         red
# 8       2        blue
# 9       1         red
# 10      2        blue
```

Comment: Like you said, not the way to do it but nicely illustrated `for/if`. Maybe annotate code for added didactic value?

Comment: ...annotated the code, hope it passes your didactic quality test ;-)

Comment: This was very helpful! There is, however, one little problem. My data contains quite a lot of NA. At this moment the loop just errors when it encounters the first NA. How do I get the loop to skip over these values?

Comment: Depends what you want the loop to do then. You have not indicated in your question that you have NA values or how to deal with them, therefore, I haven´t taken NA values into account. You simply need to add `ifelse` statements that cover NA values. I guess, you simply want to tell the R to go to the next element in this case via `next(i)` instead of executing the full code in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a factor variable coding for your condition, *e.g.:*

```
PEQTfXS_GrooteMolenbeek$group <- NA
PEQTfXS_GrooteMolenbeek$group[-1] <- PEQTfXS_GrooteMolenbeek$Q[-1] > PEQTfXS_GrooteMolenbeek$Q[-nrow(EQTfXS_GrooteMolenbeek)]
PEQTfXS_GrooteMolenbeek$group <- as.factor(PEQTfXS_GrooteMolenbeek$group)
```

(In your code above there is no provision for cases where the values are equal. the code above would put those cases in the first group)

Then you can just create your plot using *e.g.,* base `plot()` or the `ggplot2` package and use the `group` variable to code for different colours. Something like:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(date, Q, color = group, data = PEQTfXS_GrooteMolenbeek)
```

Hope this helps.